# unexpected results in evaluation of chains logical expressions javascript

Tags: javascript

I am writing a program to identify special numbers according to the criteria laid out in this code wars kata:

http://www.codewars.com/kata/catching-car-mileage-numbers

Here is a link to my full code and tests:

http://www.codeshare.io/UeXhW

I have unit tested my functions which test for each of the special number conditions and they appear to be working as expected. However, I have a function:

```
function allTests(number, awesomePhrases){
  var num = number.toString().split('');
  // if any criteria is met and the number is >99 return true
  return number > 99 && (allZeros(num) || sameDigits(num) || incrementing(num) || decrementing(num) || palindrome(number) || matchPhrase(number, awesomePhrases)) ? true : false;
}
```

which determines if any of the criteria of being a special number is met and that's not working as expected. For example, when I tested the allZeros() function on 7000 it returned true, but alltests(7000) is returning false. Is there something about how chains of logical expressions are evaluated that I don't understand or is the problem something else?

I have looked at W3schools and MDN to try and diagnose the problem.

Comment: There's no reason to use a `? :` expression if you want to return just `true` or `false`

Comment: That's a difficult line to read. In any case, it seems like it's a simple matter of debugging the full expression, step by step, no?

Comment: @DaveNewton I've been trying to via the console and results from assertEquals(). Can you recommend an IDE with debugger or some better way? I've tried the Eclipse jscript plugin but it seemed pretty involved to use for small practice codes that I usually do on code wars.

Comment: Simply, check your assumptions, ensure your order(s) of operations, everything. If I were doing it I'd just start checking the output of all the expressions and so on. I'd check your implementation(s) of things like `allZeros` preeeety carefully, though.

Comment: (E.g., check your assumptions. Think back: did you test `allZeros` in a different way? Did you switch from lax to strict comparisons? etc.) FWIW, it's debuggable using only the browser or node in about two minutes.

Comment: @DaveNewton yea, I started using parseInt in the comparisons  in allZeros() and incrementing() / decrementing() that's solving most of my problems. I think the 0s became '0's when I did toString() on the original value and my independent tests on the functions weren't catching it.

Answer (score 0):

Change all your !== to != will do.

Answer (score 0):

False results as long as *allTests()* executes with a second argument even it it's the empty string, as follows:

```
allTests(7000,"");
```

If the function is called with just one argument, i.e. the number, expect this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

The error message refers to one of the functions in the logic chain, namely  *matchPhrase()* which expects two parameters: **number** and **awesomePhrases**. If instead of providing an empty string, you use null, you'll also get the same error message.

JavaScript doesn't support the concept of default parameters  -- at least not in a way that one might expect; the parameters default to undefined.  But there is a way to work around this hurdle and improve the code so that one may avoid this needless error.  Just change *matchPhrase()* as follows:

```
   function matchPhrase(number, awesomePhrases){
      awesomePhrases = typeof awesomePhrases !== 'undefined' ?  awesomePhrases : "";
      for(var i = 0, max=awesomePhrases.length; i < max; i++){
        if(number == awesomePhrases[i]){
          return true;
        }
      }
      return false;
   }
```

The first statement accepts the second argument's value as long as it is not the undefined value; if so, then the variable gets set to the empty string. (Source for technique: [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters)).

To make the code more readily comprehensible, I suggest rewriting allTests() as follows, so that the code follows a more explicit self-documenting style:

```
    function allTests(number, awesomePhrases){
      var arrDigits = number.toString().split('');

  // if any criteria is met and the number is >99 return true
  return number > 99 && (allZeros( arrDigits ) || sameDigits( arrDigits ) || incrementing( arrDigits ) || decrementing( arrDigits) || palindrome(number) || matchPhrase(number, awesomePhrases)) ? true : false;
    }
```

This function takes a number and uses its toString() method to convert the number to a string.  The resulting string which is not visible will split itself on the empty string so that the result of arrDigits is an array of numerical strings, each one consisting of just one digit. This is the point of origin for the ensuing problem with allZeros() which compares a stringified digit with a number.

Incidentally, in the function allTests() there is an awfully lengthy ternary expression.  The syntax is fine, but you might wish to rewrite the code as follows:

```
  function getCriteriaStatus(arrDigits,number,awesomePhrases) {
    var criteria = new Array(); 
    criteria[0] = allZeros( arrDigits );
    criteria[1] = sameDigits( arrDigits );
    criteria[2] = incrementing( arrDigits );
    criteria[3] = decrementing( arrDigits);
    criteria[4] = palindrome(number);
    criteria[5] = matchPhrase(number, awesomePhrases);

    var retval = false;

    for (var i=0, max=6; i < max; i++) {
          if ( criteria[i] == true ) { 
              retval = true;
              break;
          }
    }
    return retval;
 }

function allTests(number, awesomePhrases){
  var arrDigits = number.toString().split('');
  var criteria_met = getCriteriaStatus(arrDigits,number,awesomePhrases);
  return (number > 99 && criteria_met);
}
```

To obtain the desired true result from allTests() when it invokes allZeros(), rather than complicate the code by using parseInt(), I suggest rewriting allZeros() and *any other functions* containing code that compares a numerical string value with a number  by changing from the identity operator to the equality operator.  The change involves merely replacing  `===` with `==` as well as replacing `!==` with `!=`.  The code that compares values of the same data type, using the identity operators, those operators may, and probably should, remain unchanged. (See [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Ggrevx)).